# React Hook Form - Unable to Detect Errors in Nested Values

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form

I am currently facing an issue with React Hook Form where I am unable to detect errors in nested values, specifically when using the `Controller` component. My form has a nested structure, and I am using the `useFormContext` hook to access the `errors` object globally.

Here is a simplified version of my component structure:

```
import { useFormContext, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import { TextInput, HelperText } from 'react-native-paper';

const InputTextController = ({ name, label, ...props }) => {
  const { errors } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <>
          <TextInput
            label={label}
            value={field.value}
            onBlur={field.onBlur}
            onChangeText={(value) => field.onChange(value)}
            error={!!errors[name]}
          />
          <HelperText type="error" visible={!!errors[name]}> // name="obj.nestedObj.value"
            {errors[name]?.message}
          </HelperText>
        </>
      )}
      name={name}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
```

While this works perfectly for non-nested fields, I am facing difficulties in detecting errors for nested values. The errors object does not seem to capture errors in the nested structure.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or could provide guidance on how to handle errors in nested values with React Hook Form?

Any help or insights into this problem would be greatly appreciated!